# the map doesn't show up

Tags: android, google-maps

i have a problem with my simple google map in android

here is my MapsActivity.java

```
package udin.MapsActivity;

import com.google.android.maps.MapActivity;
import com.google.android.maps.MapView;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MapsActivity extends MapActivity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }
    @Override
    protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
        return false;
    }
}
```

and this is my main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <com.google.android.maps.MapView 
        android:id="@+id/mapView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:apiKey="00j2bA4ivSvH0cSDJJ4aiPiVCq_OSH0adwf6I2w"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

and this is my AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="udin.MapsActivity"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">
    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity android:name=".MapsActivity"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
    </application>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

</manifest>
```

when i run this, its have no error in DDMS

but why the map doesn't show up like this

[image: googlemap]

the code for GoogleMap API is right...

yesterday i try this code is work for me....but now why this isn't work?

can anyone help??why this is happening?
i will really appreciate if you can help me
Thank You

Comment: Is there anything in the logs?

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2641197/1777090 , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9872469/mapview-showing-in-grey-tiles-map-not-showing-in-android-google-api-2-3-3

Comment: the log doesn't show anything wrong (or red)....it just like normally i run my program in android

Comment: @Safarudin : how you have created MD5 using default keystore or any other?

Comment: i create MD5 with step from this site [link](http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/using-google-maps-android) .... 

is there any chance if my API key is expired?

Comment: Different emulator use  differnt key..

Comment: @Safarudin : which version of java you are using java 6 or java 7?

Comment: i dont know what version java i use, but i use jdk1.6.0_03 and jre1.6.0_03

Comment: Make sure you have selected google api

Comment: Please!! check [this](http://rdcworld-android.blogspot.in/2012/07/google-map-tutorial-android-advance.html) may help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try putting the uses-permissions tags above the application in the manifest file.  Also, I think that occasionally the signing between Eclipse and the Emulator gets messed up, and restarting both can sometimes fix the issue.